# Finding particular character in a line in bash

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell

Is there a way to extract a particular part from a line of text with regular expression in bash.

For example

```
8495 pts/1 S 0:10 /opt/sbin/proc -q 10 -p /opt/etc/plugin/ -c /opt/etc/ -f 200000 -s 10000 -b 3276
```

How can I extract q parameter **10** from above?. I need the number after q parameter

Comment: Is this typed on the command line? Or stored in a file?

Comment: @spencer it is the output of ps aux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
px aux | sed -n 's/.*-q\s\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/p'
```

Answer (score 0):

The naive solution regex would be `.*-q ([^ ]*) .*`. So, something like `sed 's/.*-q ([^ ]*) .*/\1/'` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If the line is stored in variable `$line`:

```
val=$(
    this_token=false 
    for word in $line; do 
        $this_token && { echo $word; break; } 
        [[ $word = "-q" ]] && this_token=true 
    done
) 
echo $val
```